# How to generate orthogonal matrix in Octave?

Tags: matlab

How to generate an orthogonal matrix in Octave?

I saw something like that

```
gallery('orthog',n,k)
```

in `matlab`, but I can't find any similar function in Octave.

Thanks!

Comment: For those of you who land here today, octave has been extended since the answer was given.  There is now a `gallery("orthog",n,k)` command in octave; see `doc gallery`.  However, it should be noted that for a given `n`, the matrix returned is fixed.  It is not random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can apply QR to a given random matrix: `[q, r] = qr (a)`. The matrix `q` will be orthogonal.
2. You can use orthogonal basis computation: `Q = orth(A)` on a random matrix `A`.